# Почему не срабатывает if (response.Cookies != null)?

Tags: c#

Вот код:

```
if (response.Cookies != null)
    Cookie.Add(response.Cookies);
```

Компилятор говорит:

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на
> экземпляр объекта.

Решил задачу так:

```
        if (response.Cookies.Count != null)
            Cookie.Add(response.Cookies);
```

Но любопытно, почему не сработала проверка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count - число, оно не будет null никогда. (сомневаюсь что там "int?")

А ошибка была скорее всего в том что response - уже был равен null.

Comment: Все таки int. Я сегодня плохо соображаю что-то.
response != null.
Буквально пару дней назад этот код работал, и я его не менял. Даже не могу понять в чем проблема :(

Comment: Если response = null, то почему тогда if (response.Cookies.Count != 0) работает?

Comment: Код может быть рабочим в "тепличных условиях" - добавте в него какие-нибудь дополнительные проверки, что бы убедиться что в него приходит то что и должно приходить (ошибка может быть в другом месте, например, которое изменилось, либо изменилось что-то в окружении и т.д.).